# How to load category on catalog_category_view page based on the collection returned from ProductRepository::getList()

Tags: magento, magento2

Is there any short customization that can be done to make catalog_category_view page load products based on some product attributes such as special_price, cost, and special_date_from without specifying any specific category Id. Reason is - I don't want people to go back and start assigning products to specific categories just to be able to load it in catalog_category_view page.

It appears catalog/category/view page is hardwired to load product based on category Id

Answer (score 0):

In the block page responsible for load the products you can add an method . 
In that class you inject:

```
use \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory as ProductCollectionFactory;
```

On your constructor:

```
$this->_productsFactory = $productsFactory;
```

And in mehod:

```
$collection = $this->_productsFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect(
                    '*'
            )->addAttributeToFilter('product_brandname', array('neq' => ''))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('price', array(
        array('gt' => 0.01, 'lt' => 99999999),
            )
    );
```

Comment: no problem. Please, if this worked please check as a right answear